# "Smell" algorithm: calculate value in a grid based on neighbours with recursion (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create an algorithm that for any given point in a grid (2d list - with some obstacles/walls), calculates a  value for each of the grid cells.

This value depends on the distance through the 'maze' from the original point.
The starting point would have value "1", and for each cell you move away from the point the value would decrease (e.g. 0.9).

Ultimately I will use this algorithm to allow a pac-man style ghost to chase pac-man through the maze by following the smell track (Might not be the best algorithm to do so, but I'm doing this as an exercise, so please let's stick to this).

This is the code I have so far:

I have defined a function to find the "highest neighbour" (hN) in a grid, which works fine:

```
def hN(grid, x, y):
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = 0
    if x > 0 and y > 0: #all the conditions ensure that no error are given at the edges
        a = grid[x-1][y-1]
    if x > 0:
        b = grid[x-1][y]
    if x > 0 and y < len(grid[0]):
        c = grid[x-1][y+1]
    if y > 0:
        d = grid[x][y-1]
    if y < len(grid[0]):
        e = grid[x][y+1]
    if x < len(grid) and y > 0:
        f = grid[x+1][y-1]
    if x < len(grid):
        g = grid[x+1][y]
    if x < len(grid) and y < len(grid[0]):
        h = grid[x+1][y+1]
    return max(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
```

Below I have the "smell fill" functiosn (smell as it will calculate a "smell" which is stronger next to the target - fill as I'm basing this on flood fill).

2 parts: the first part ("works") is the recursive part, the second function will be than called as it will set the initial cell value to 1

```
def smellFillWork(grid, smellGrid, x, y):
if grid[x][y] == 1: #base case: the "maze" grid has 1s as walls and 0s as 'floors'.
    return
else: #set the 4 neighbours UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT to *0.9
    if x > 0:
        smellGrid[x-1][y] = hN(smellGrid, x-1, y) * 0.9
    if y > 0:
        smellGrid[x][y-1] = hN(smellGrid, x, y-1) * 0.9
    if x < len(grid)-1:
        smellGrid[x+1][y] = hN(smellGrid, x+1, y) * 0.9
    if y < len(grid[0])-1:
        smellGrid[x][y+1] = hN(smellGrid, x, y+1) * 0.9

#here the recursion is called:
if x > 0:
    smellFillWork(grid, smellGrid, x - 1, y)
if y > 0:
    smellFillWork(grid, smellGrid, x, y - 1)
if x < len(grid) - 1:
    smellFillWork(grid, smellGrid, x + 1, y)
if y < len(grid[0]) - 1:
    smellFillWork(grid, smellGrid, x, y + 1)




def smellFill(grid, smellGrid, x, y):
    smellGrid[x][y] = 1 #set the initial cell at 1
    smellFillWork(grid,smellGrid, x, y) # call the function above
```

Any idea why the above doesn't work? I get an infinite recursion loop.

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner and pretty much self-taught, excuse my poor style

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not read every line of code you wrote but why don't you write a distance function which finds for an arbitrary point in the grid the number of steps you are away from the source of the smell. Say the output of the distance function is `n`, then calculate `0.9 ^ n`.

If you wan to stay closer to your own solution then I think you'd better avoid a recursive solution. You just have to write an algorithm which populates cells starting at the cell which produces the smell.

From your description it is not clear enough whether obstacles/walls matter.

Comment: A direct distance won't do. Think of it as a maze (pacman / bomberman), a direct distance would go over the "walls". (I do realise that my description wasn't great, in my defence it was very clear in my mind)

Comment: @TomM True, because of the obstacles/walls you probably need a shortest path algorithm. This algorithm is well documented. You might even want an modified version of the algorithm which computes for the entire grid the path-length to the source.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to calculate the shortest path for each of the cells in a given section of my grid (delimited by walls), I guess I should start from my selected point (the one with assigned value 1). In which order would you progress the calculation? That's where I thought at basing this on flood fill would be easier.

Comment: @TomM Like I said, the shortest path algorithm is a well known algorithm. I am sure there is already a Python implementation somewhere doing exactly what you want: computing the shortest path (= no of steps) for each cell to the source. The alternative, the flood fill algo, might do the job as well, however is less straightforward. I would not use recursion for your flood fill algo.